# Trying to access razor page from view in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I need to access a razor page content when pressing button in my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC view.

The problem is, when I press the button, it gives me parameters of desired razor page link in the form of query string parameters in the view.

Here is my code:

```
public class AdminController : Controller 
{
    public IActionResult All()
    {
        var vm = new IndexUserVM()
        {
            Users = _admin.GetAll(),
            RolaAll = _admin.GetRolaAll()
        };

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

`All.cshtml`:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" id="forgot-password" 
   asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/ForgotPassword">
   Change password
</a>
```

But when I press the button trying to access the razor page from my view, there is no result and the following URL is displayed on top:

```
https://localhost:77777/Admin/All?area=Identity&page=%2FForgotPassword
```

Comment: Please forgive for asking such a stupid question, I forgot to add Account/ForgotPassword